# Using boto3 in lambda with SNS & EMR client to fetch the details of cluster and send it over to the mail

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm able to get the output and send it over the email using the SNS service in the below code. However, it is sending a mail for 1 cluster output at a time rather then sending all the cluster details in 1 mail.

import boto3
import json
from datetime import timedelta

REGION = 'us-east-1'

Topic_Arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000:testlog"

emrclient = boto3.client('emr', region_name=REGION)
snsclient = boto3.client('sns', region_name=REGION)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    EMRS = emrclient.list_clusters(
    ClusterStates = ['STARTING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING']
    )

```
clusters = EMRS["Clusters"]
for cluster_details in clusters :
    id = cluster_details.get("Id")

    describe_cluster = emrclient.describe_cluster(
        ClusterId = id
        )
    cluster_values = describe_cluster["Cluster"]
    name = cluster_values.get("Name")

    tag_val = cluster_values.get("Tags")
    Instancehours = cluster_values.get("NormalizedInstanceHours")


    emr_ig = emrclient.list_instance_groups(
     ClusterId = id
     )
    emrid = emr_ig["InstanceGroups"]
    for item in emrid :
        purchase_type = item.get("Market")
        instancegroup_id = item.get("Id")
        instancegroup_type = item.get("InstanceGroupType")
        status = item.get("Status")
        state = status.get("State")
        timeline = status.get("Timeline")
        autoscaling = item.get("AutoScalingPolicy", None)
        #autoscaling_status = autoscaling.get("Status")
        #autoscaling_state = autoscaling_status.get("State")
        create_date_time = timeline.get("CreationDateTime")
        ready_date_time = timeline.get("ReadyDateTime")
        emrdetails = "Cluster_ID = " + id + "," + "status_of_cluster = " + state + "," + " Instance_Group = " + instancegroup_type + "," + " Market = " + purchase_type + "," + " CreationDateTime = " + str(create_date_time) + "," + " NormalizedInstanceHours = " + str(Instancehours) + "," + " Autosacle = " + str(autoscaling)
        emr_status_list = []
        emr_status_list.append(emrdetails)

        emrStatusCheck = []
        for emr_status in emr_status_list :
            if ((emr_status.split(",")[3]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("ON_DEMAND") and (emr_status.split(",")[2]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("CORE") and (emr_status.split(",")[6]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("None")):
                emrStatusCheck.append(emr_status)
                print(emrStatusCheck)

                  snsclient.publish(
                      TopicArn =  Topic_Arn,
                      Subject = "EMR Cluster Details",
                      Message = emrStatusCheck
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the sns statement out of the for loop, so that executes only once. Example :

```
for emr_status in emr_status_list :
    if ((emr_status.split(",")[3]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("ON_DEMAND") and (emr_status.split(",")[2]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("CORE") and (emr_status.split(",")[6]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("None")): 

        emrStatusCheck.append(emr_status) 
        print(emrStatusCheck) 
snsclient.publish( TopicArn = Topic_Arn, Subject = "EMR Cluster Details", Message = emrStatusCheck )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, move the SNS publish statement outside for loop. You may also need to aggregate the messages for each cluster into a single composite message